# How do I call a category on Microsoft Power Apps?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, dynamics-365

I'm having troubles inserting this Bookable Resource Category via a GUID on Power Automate in a lookup field- Same method wokred fine on contacts/accountrs with the accounts(GUID)syntax but it doesn't want to work for this case.
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDuSj.png)
I want to call it in power automate using this technique ( I have used it with slash as well but I still get the same result)
[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbuQF.png)

But I still get an error
[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0T4v.png)
And I get this error:
URL was not parsed due to an ODataUnrecognizedPathException. Resource not found for the segment provided in the URL.

Can anyone help? Did anyone do something similar? Please & thank you.

I tried to put a guid for a bookable resource category on power automate but it doesn't compile.
I'm expecting it to create me a new record with the right GUID in the lookup field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use /bookableresourcecategories(GUID) instead of bookableresourcecategories(GUID)

Comment: I have tried that already but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your issue is not at the bookable resource category look up field, but at either the calendar ID or project ID fields, if you're passing a GUID you must also provide the EntitySetName for it.

[image]